# Changing "for loop" to "while loop"

Tags: python

Wondering how would the following for loop be changed to while loop.

While having the same output.

```
for i in range(0,20, 4):
     print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

as simple as that:

```
i = 0
while i < 20:
    print(i)
    i += 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
while i < 20:
    print(i)
    i += 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

```
i = 1
while i < 20:
  print(i)
  i += 4
```

you can also visit here for more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
while(i<5):
    print(4*i)
    i+=1
```