# How do i convert for loop to while loop?

Tags: python

Hi I just got a confusion in this thing. How do i convert for loop to equivalent while loop?
Suppose can anyone give me example by solving this..

```
for number in range(20,2,-2):
    print("number",number)
```

will be really appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing "for loop" to "while loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790697/changing-for-loop-to-while-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this doing loop like this

```
x = 20
while x >= 4:
    print("number", x)
    x -= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

simply, you add count variable.

e.g

```py
for number in range(20,2,-2):
 print(number)
```

```py
count = 2
while True:
 if(count < 2):
 break
print(number)
count -=2
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, this is the equivalent using a while loop:

```
number = 20
while(number > 2):
    print("number",number)
    number -= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more adaptable sequence, you can use the following code.
It uses an iterator to make the loop using a while.
You just need to set up the numbers of the sequence.

```
from_number = 20
to_number = 2
step = -2

print("Loop with for")
for number in range(from_number, to_number, step):
    print("number",number)


print("Loop with while")
iterator = iter(range(from_number, to_number, step))
number = next(iterator)
while number:
    print("number",number)
    try:
        number = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        number = None
```